# How to implement horizontal auto scroll of recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implementing a custom linear layout manager in android. For getting a horizontal auto sliding recyclerview. but I am facing some issues when I try to call my custom class into my main java class.

The issues I am facing with my codes are listed below.

```
public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }
```

Error which i am getting is: Constructor 'CustomLinearLayoutManager(android.content.Context, int, boolean)' is never used

```
 public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
```

Error which i am getting is: Constructor 'CustomLinearLayoutManager(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)' is never used

```
customLinearLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition();
```

An error which I am facing for this line is:

smoothScrollToPosition() in CustomLinearLayoutManager cannot be applied to:
Expected Parameters:                    Actual Arguments:
 recyclerView:                            RecyclerView
 state:                                     State
position:                                    int

Custom Java Class

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
        final LinearSmoothScroller linearSmoothScroller =
                new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {
                    private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 200f;

                    @Override
                    public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                        return CustomLinearLayoutManager.this
                                .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel
                            (DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                        return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                    }
                };
        linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
    }
}
```

Main Java Class:

```
CustomLinearLayoutManager customLinearLayoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        customLinearLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition();
            recyclerViewHeaderSlider = view.findViewById(R.id.bannerSlider);
            SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
            snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewHeaderSlider);
            recyclerViewHeaderSlider.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerViewHeaderSlider.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
            headerSliderAdapter.setOnClick(this);
            recyclerViewHeaderSlider.setAdapter(headerSliderAdapter);
```

Please tell the solution of the above-mentioned error. also, please exact code in order to achieve horizontal auto-slide recyclerview. with the custom linear layout manager which I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the normal linear layout manager and set the orientation to horizontal

Comment: I believe you shouldn't answer a question with a question.